What happens when there is a draw for the Gold Saucer date?
During Chapter 12 of FF7 Rebirth the party member that you have the strongest bond with  takes you to see the Loveless play aswell as ride the Skywheel. After you finish the game, You can manually set which character will accompany you, but you can also still leave it up to the game to decide, depending on your "closest companion". Additionally in the play log you can now see each character's percentage values, telling you which character would be assined to you for the event.
What happens when you don't choose your companion manually and there are multiple characters with the same highest percentage value? For example if you max out all the character's values to 100% and then let the game decide who you get for that scene. Is it determined at random? Does the game use a tie-breaker system where certain characters get prioritized over others, e.g. you will always get Aerith if there is a draw and she is one of the possible candidates? Or does the game perhaps default to the "Others" (Cait Sith, Vincent and Cid) which you normally only get when you don't have enough reputation with any of the 5 possible characters?

Rebirth Relationship Mechanic Explained (I think) by Moon_Moon29, 8 months ago on Reddit:

There are some tiebreakers that give some progress to a character at the cost of locking off some of it for another. I mentioned earlier that Tifa and Aerith can not have the same standing as each other at any of the dates, this is why.

So if there's a priority system for who gets the date if any of the single-person-dates are at the same rankings for everything, it'll be rarely used since that's so unlikely to happen.
If somehow everyone's at max, then Final Fantasy VII Rebirth Relationship guide: How to Romance right to pick your Gold Saucer Date by Alex Donaldson on 03 March, 2024 says:

Cait Sith, Vincent, & Cid (as a group)

While that last group doesn't have a relationship stat to speak of, their date exists as a sort of tiebreaker resolution - if you don't have a clear lead with any of the others, Cloud will enjoy a 'boys night' with that trio.

